# Ecclesiastes 9:5 "...quia oblivioni tradita est *memoria eorum*." - "memory containing them" or "memory they posessed in their heads"?

Tags: vulgata

In the Vulgate in Ecclesiastes 9:5, it says "*...quia oblivioni tradita est **memoria eorum**.*". Does that mean "*...because the **memory containing them** has been given to oblivion.*" or does that mean "*...because the **memory they posessed in their heads** has been given to oblivion.*"? Or maybe something else?

Comment: The Bible is the single most frequently translated document in human history. Have you considered checking what other people made of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer:  Something else.

The original reads: ”כִּי נִשְׁכַּח זִכְרָם“ (Ecclesiastes 9:5 BHS-T). ("For their memory is forgotten.")  "their memory" could either be...

- Subjective: The memory that they have
- Objective: The memory others have towards them

Jerome, evidently, wanted to keep the ambiguity of the Hebrew intact in his Latin. For "memoria eorum" could be either subjective or objective (as it is in the Hebrew).

This built-in ambiguity is retained in all the versional support for the verse:

- “ὅτι ἐπελήσθη ἡ μνήμη αὐτῶν·” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 LXXS-T) ("For the memory of them is forgotten.")
- “in oblivione enim venit memoria eorum.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 V-LATINA). ("For their memory goes into oblivion.")
- ”ܡܛܠ ܕܐܬܛܥܝ ܕܘܟܪܢܗܘܢ.“ (Ecclesiastes 9:5 PESHOT-T). ("On account of the fact that their memory goes away.")

Finally, the English versions have to take a stand on one side or the other (subjective/objective).  Here's a list of some English versions, showing the fact that they are divided.  Some keep the built in ambiguity, though, by simply translating, "Their memory", leaving the reader to decided if that's a person's memory of them, or their own memory.

- “because the memory of them is forgotten.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 CSB17)
- “and even the memory of them is lost.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 NRSV)
- “They have no further reward, nor are they remembered.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 NLT-SE)
- “and even the memory of them disappears.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 NET)
- “and they have no more reward, for the memory of them is forgotten” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 ESV)

Comment: I don't think the Hebrew is ambiguous, actually: [every other instance of זֵכֶר](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/strongs_2143.htm) plus a possessive suffix in the Bible pretty clearly seems to have the objective reading (and from context so does this one, really), and whenever it talks about blotting out the memory *from* something it always uses a construction with the preposition מִן. (It's also perfectly possible to preserve that sort of ambiguity in English by just saying "their memory" instead of "the memory of them", and the fact that translators don't is a choice.)

Comment: Actually, rereading, are you saying some of those English translations are going for the subjective reading? They're literally all objective.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, there's no min in this verse at all. linking together this verse (contextually) with others that contain a min is arriving at a conclusion that is not tenable.

Comment: @Cairnarvon "memory of them" is somewhat ambiguous.  The NIV & NLT definitely go objective though: “and even their name is forgotten.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 NIV11-GKE); “They have no further reward, nor are they remembered.” (Ecclesiastes 9:5 NLT-SE)

Comment: @Cairnarvon The examples you list show the weakness of using a concordance, rather than plowing with one's own heifer and looking at the verses in in context. In Psa. 9:7, "אָבַד זִכְרָם הֵמָּה", it is not provable in context whether it's subjective or objective. Likewise, in Psalm 30:5, the subject of "לְזֵכֶר קָדְשׁוֹ" is not known. Yes, the people thank God, but is it for him making his holiness known, or for them making his holiness known?  In that compressed poetry it's difficult to tell.  Your evidence is not convincing.

Comment: The thing about this concordance is that you can just click through to the context. Are you sure you understand the difference between the meaning of an objective and a subjective genitive construction? If you want to read לְזֵכֶר קָדְשׁוֹ in Psalm 30:4 subjectively the abstract holiness of YHWH itself must be doing the remembering (it's not about making known), and in Psalm 9:6 a subjective reading of "you have destroyed their cities and their memory has perished" necessitates positing an outbreak of dementia among the enemies, which clearly isn't the intended reading.

Comment: @Cairnarvon, or, in Psalm 9:6 it could just simply mean, that when they die, and their brain cells are decomposing, their decomposing brains have a hard time keeping their thoughts in long-term memory.

Comment: @Cairnarvon As to Psalm 30:4, cp Psa. 114:4, where "זֵכֶר עָשָׂה לְנִפְלְאֹתָיו" is clearly used in a causative sense.  Sure, "עָשָׂה" is added pleonastically. But the usage of "זֵכֶר" is clearly causative.

Comment: Re: Psalm 9:6, that's a joke, right? As for the rest, you're misunderstanding the structure of Psalm 11**1**:4 as well: עָשָׂה is the verb and not used "pleonastically", זֵכֶר is a noun and the object of that verb, and none of it is relevant to this discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147587/discussion-between-epimanes-and-cairnarvon).